# How to I select a distinct count of a column on SSRS 2008?

Tags: reporting-services

Im using SSRS 2008. I am counting a column with the title "Good". When i run the information if the column comes back with a Y it means yes if an N it means no. I am counting the Y's of the column. Here is the catch sometimes the information comes back twice. That is suppose to happen but when it comes back with Y even though it is the same information i only want it to count 1 of those Y's. What is the correct formula i can use to do this? My current formula is =Count(Fields!Good.Value) What can i add on to this or change this to make it do this?

Comment: try this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255245.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesnt make sense to me, I think you have probably left out the context of your distinct requirement.

Anyway, as it is asked, I would try:

=CountDistinct( Iif ( Fields!Good.Value = "Y" , Fields!Good.Value  , Nothing ) )

Answer (score 0):

This formula will count the Ys in the column:

```
=sum(Iif(Fields!Good.Value = "Y",1,0))
```

Note:  It assumes that you have your data structured such that every row is counted.  You'll need to set some kind of flag or something in the table if you want to exclude some of the Ys and modify the above formula to check for that flag.

Best practice would be to structure your data so it doesn't have any duplicate rows.  Either a filter at the SSRS dataset, or at the datasource.